# Where is the samba name "workstation" coming from?

Tags: mac-osx, samba, hostname

The output of `smbstatus` running on OS X Mavericks with the latest Server app installed (but with native SMB shut down in favor of the Samba implementation from Homebrew) contains many entries like this one

> IPC$         85975   workstation   Tue Aug  5 11:58:03 2014

I've worked out that all of these users are connecting via OS X.  All users who connect through Windows have their computer name displayed.  I have checked on my own OS X machine (with computer name, local host name, and host name all set) and I even show up as "workstation."  Where is this name coming from?  How can I change it?

Answer (score 0):

If it is the homebrew implementation of smb, then this might be located somewhere there :
/usr/local/Cellar/

Out of curiosity, what is your netbios name ? (SysPref / Network / Advanced / WINS) ?

Comment: The NetBIOS name is the same as the other three.  The client side is the OS X SMB implementation, but the server is homebrew (because I couldn't figure out how to map a bad user to guest on Apple's version when Windows users tried to connect.  I think I figured it out but I can't switch to test while it is being used by all my coworkers).  I'll have a look and see what the server is up in /usr/local/Cellar

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a different name, and was running around frantically trying to figure it out. Turns out the answer is very simple, and it's in System Preferences.

1. On the Mac that is file sharing, open up System Preferences.
2. Click on "Network", and select the network you are currently sharing on. (For me, it would be Wi-Fi.)

[image: network_preference_pane]

3. Click on the "Advanced..." button.
4. Select the "WINS" tab.

[image: wins_pane_network_preferences]

5. From here, the culprit should be clearly visible as the NetBIOS name. It should also tell you if it's currently being used or not (as of El Capitan.)

Regardless of whatever setting for the name you have in your Sharing preferences, it will always override the name that SMB users see with the NetBIOS name from your Network preferences.

Comment: I posted the photos as links since I can't display photos without 10 rep.

Comment: Why couldn't you embed images? Just takes a `!` in front of the image tags you put in (look at my edits).